# Турнир в NN Имяреков пропустит/пропустил/пропускает?

Tags: стилистика

***Турнир в Пекине Ронни О'Салливан пропустил.***

Услышал комментатора - и почему-то не было ни малейшего сомнения,что этот турнир еще впереди. Так и оказалось. Проблема в том, что турнир еще не начался, но участник на него уже не поедет - заявку не подал, не допущен - не столь важно, поезд ушел. Я-то комментатора понял, а вот как другие?!

Футбольные комментаторы используют настоящее или будущее время (как,кстати, лучше?!).
*Костоломов пропускает матч с "Мазилами" из-за перебора карточек*.

Но у нас случай несколько другой.

Answer (score 2):

Тот, кто в теме, поймёт комментатора правильно, а остальным разницы нет.

А вообще, формы прошедшего времени главным образом употребляются в своем основном значении, относя действие в план прошлого (имперфективный, перфектный, аористический).

Очень редко формы прошедшего времени используются в переносном значении, т.е. в значении настоящего и будущего времени.

Боялся я его, как же! = не боюсь (наст. вр.)

Как же, послушалась она его! – в знач. буд. вр.

Так тебе и поверили! – в знач. буд. вр.

Костоломов пропускает матч с "Мазилами" из-за перебора карточек.

Формы настоящего времени имеют 2 основных значения: настоящее актуальное и настоящее неактуальное.
1.Настоящее актуальное обозначает такое действие, которое совпадает с моментом речи.

2.Чаще всего формы настоящего времени употребляются в других значениях и обозначают действие, которое только частично совпадает или вообще не совпадает с моментом речи. Такое значение называют настоящим неактуальным.

Разновидности этого значения.

А) Обозначает действие вообще, привычное, регулярное. Его называют абстрактным. Глагол с таким значением может сочетаться со словами всегда, часто, обычно. *Обычно дети спят крепко. Он всегда все знает.* Особенно часто такое значение встречается в пословицах: *лес рубят – щепки летят.*

Б) Настоящее постоянного действия. Обозначает непрерывно протекающее действие, и этим оно отличается от абстрактного настоящего. *Рязань стоит на Оке. Ока впадает в Волгу. Мальчик растет быстро. Река течет на север.*

В) Настоящее расширенное – обозначает действие, которое началось давно и только частично совпадает с моментом речи. *Я собираю материал к курсовой работе. Уже 3 года, как я учусь в университете. Я давно уже живу не сердцем, а головой. Несколько лет я пишу этот роман.*

Г) Настоящее потенциальное обозначает не действие в момент речи, а только способность к нему (действию вообще). *Он пишет стихи. Она хорошо вяжет.*

Д) Настоящее изобразительное используется при поэтическом описании (обычно в стихотворных текстах): *Сижу за решеткой в темнице сырой…*

Переносное употребление форм настоящего времени

1. Для описания событий прошлого (настоящее историческое) – используется форма настоящего времени, а передается значение прошедшего времени. *Поздней осенью Пушкин приезжает в Болдино.* 
   Часто настоящее историческое употребляется с частицей бывало: Бывало, выходишь утром в сад и вдыхаешь запах сирени. Часто формам настоящего времени в этом значении предшествуют формы прошедшего времени в прямом значении: *Птица вспорхнула и летит стрелой.*
2. Для обозначения действия ближайшего будущего. Обычно это или воображаемое, или намеченное действие.

   - *Значит, едешь? – спросила мать.*
   - *Еду.*
   - *И когда?*
   - *С первым поездом.*

*Скоро начинаются экзамены. Вообразите, что вы встречаетесь через много лет.*

Так что русский язык богат, выражайте как хотите - Ваш выбор.

Comment: Я-то как раз был "не в теме". Понятия не имел, когда там єтот турнир был или будет. Это-то и интересно... И такой вот вариант с прошедшим временем: * "Считайте, турнир уже пропустил"*.

Answer (score 0):

Моя робкая версия, что комментатор передал интонацией отношение к факту как еще не свершившемуся, но предопределенному.

В определенных кругах такое используется для приказа: *Первый(,) пошел! Упал - отжался!* и тому подобное. Или сократил фразу "Считайте, что (уже) пропустил" - тоже передал это интонацией.

Но это именно версия. Никогда ничего подобного ранее не слышал, материала для анализа нет. Хотя чего только от комментаторов не услышишь.

Comment: Вполне профессиональная версия. Именно так. В его уме это уже свершившееся событие.

Comment: @Людмила так понятно, что ***в его уме*** так. Вопрос, как это он донес до меня - и других, кто "не в теме". Я предположил, что нужной интонацией. Сейчас-то я уже и не вспомню его голос

Comment: Ну, интонацией он мог передать сожаление, сочувствие или какое-то ещё чувство. Хотя, если произнести врастяжку, то будет звучать убедительно. Так что возможно.